# How is everyone storing connectionstrings?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, connection-string

I was wondering if people could post their solution to the ongoing problem of local databases and different connectionstrings among many developers in one project within source control?

More specifically, I'm talking about the problem where a project that is in source control and has many developers with a local database each. Each developer has their own connection string (named instance, default instance, machine name, username, password, etc). Every check in overrides the previous version and pulling the latest version results in using someone else's connection string.

So, people, which solution are you using for this problem? Extra points for explanations on why their solution works, pros, and cons.

**EDIT**
Keep in mind that this answer shouldn't be targeted only to an enterprise environment where you have full control of the setup. The right solution should work for everyone: enterprise, startup, and open source devs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, your question seems to imply one of two outcomes:

1. A connection string is specified in the Web.config file that is generic enough to work for all local versions of the database. You've indicated that this isn't an ideal setup in environments where you don't have complete control.
2. Each developer is required to supply his or her own connection string that is never checked into source control.

A few others have already covered the first scenario. Use localhost and follow a convention for the database name. For option 2, I'd recommend specifying a config source that doesn't get checked into source control:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:

connectionStrings.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Name" 
    providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
    connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx

connectionStrings.config would be a file in the root of the project that you specifically excluded from source control. Each developer would be required to provide this file when working locally. Your production connection string could be substituted via a Web.config transformation on build / deployment.

Comment: Great solution! Exactly what I was looking for and didn't know that was doable

Answer (score 5):

All of our development stations are setup somewhat the same.

1. We use integrated authentication to the database, so no user/password needs to be stored.
2. Everyone uses the default instance.
3. Since they are all local databases, you can user localhost.
4. Same database name

So a connection string might end up being:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

And everyone uses that.

Comment: This works very well on an enterprise environment. I modified the question to add more requirements.

Comment: I think it is fair to require devs on a non-enterprise project to make some local configuration to get the own environment ready for developing. +1

Comment: I don't think it is. If you participate in many projects you can't expect that dev to have a dev environment for each project.

Answer (score 1):

We have a test database that runs on it's own server. It is just test data actually replicated from the live server every night.
All developers use this for testing. It is true data but non critical as it is a day old.
We store the connection strings in the web.config of course. I have a function to get the connection string from the web.config and I just look if it is localhost return the test connection string. if not then return the live connection string.
This works for us. And we just don't use local databases.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen various methods used.

i) You only maintain a live connection string and developers make modifications to the relevant module and never check it in.

ii) An app.config is maintained with the connection strings and it is a shared file as far as source control is concerned.

iii) In debug config, connection string details are passed in the command line from the IDE.